# Solving linear equation systems with tensors in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have three tensors *v_1*, *v_2* and *v_3*, each of shape `n x 3`. And three tensors *v_1'*, *v_2'* and *v_3'*, also each of shape `n x 3`. I want to compute a tensor which stores *n* `3 x 3` matrices *M_i*, each solving the equation system

> M_i * v_1_i = v_1_i'

> M_i * v_2_i = v_2_i'

> M_i * v_3_i = v_3_i'

It is guaranteed that this has one solution by construction. I just need the calculation for the rotation matrices. I tried `torch.linalg.solve`, but I can't figure out how to reshape the tensors correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It appears that your systems are underdetermined: For each of the `n` systems you have a matrix of 3x3 unknowns, and two vectors of each 3 entries, right?

Comment: Each matrix is constrained by three vectors v_k_i and their target vectors v_k_i'. So this has one solution for each i.

Comment: This means each of these three vectors has length `n`, how are we supposed to multiplay a vector of length `n` with a 3x3 matrix? Could you maybe provide a concrete example of just one such system? Or actually provide an [MCVE] with some exemplary data of these vectors an matrices.